# Como puedo consumir un servicio SOAP desde C# API REST

Tags: c#, api, rest, soap, wcf

Tengo un proyecto `API REST,` desde el cual debo consumir un `SOAP WCF`.

No encuentro como consumirlo desde mi aplicación, encuentro ejemplos pero creando el proyecto `WCF`, el cual no se si puedo agregar a mi proyecto existente.

[image: Estructura de mi proyecto]

Quiero saber en que proyecto podría agregar el `WCF` o la referencia al servicio para consumirlo, la verdad es que no tengo experiencia manejando `WFC SOAP`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo depende de tu visión como quieres tener de separado. Nosotros en empresa normalmente para consumo de los datos externos creamos un proyecto separado y lo incluimos en la solución. Esto si hay pocos proyectos. Si solución tiene muchos, pues crear un proyecto solo para esto la hace crecer aún mas, asi que en estos casos añadimos referencias solo a los servicios externos necesarios en cada proyecto.
Pulsas boton derecho sobre el proyecto y le añades esta referencia que buscas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al crear el cliente tienes que pensar sobretodo en como vas a proteger los datos, si peticiones seran sincronas o asincronas. Que tipo de datos utilizar para las colleciones y para diccionarios.

Answer (score 3):

Segun la imagen que nos muestras la referencia al servicio deberia realizarla en el proyecto de `Bussines` o en algun otro separado y referencialo desde este

Si lo separas es porque quieres abstraer la funcionalidad y poder `mockear` la funcionalidad para pder generar `test` en el codigo.

[Walkthrough: Create a simple WCF service in Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-wcf-service-in-windows-forms?view=vs-2017)

Analiza el titulo "Obtener acceso al servicio" alli explica paso a paso como referenciar el servicio.

Pero basicamente usas la opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ten en cuenta que creara un `app.config` en ese proyecto del cual deberas tomar la seccion de configuracion del servicio y llevarla al `web.config` del proyecto de `api rest`, porque es este quien inicial y desde donde todas las dll toman la configuracion